spring boot starter opentelemetry getting ClasNotFound for DoubleGauge
so I can't even seem to find what library contains this, but for the spring-boot-starter-opentelemetry, when booting up Spring Boot, I get the following error.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk' defined in class path resource [io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/spring/autoconfigure/OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration$OpenTelemetrySdkConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.opentelemetry.sdk.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk]: Factory method 'autoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk' threw exception with message: io/opentelemetry/api/incubator/metrics/DoubleGauge
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ...
    ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.opentelemetry.sdk.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk]: Factory method 'autoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk' threw exception with message: io/opentelemetry/api/incubator/metrics/DoubleGauge
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ...
    ... 148 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.api.incubator.metrics.DoubleGauge
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 166 common frames omitted

I'm using gradle, with the toml entries being
spring-boot-starter-opentelemetry = {group = "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation", name = "opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter", version = { ref = "opentelemetry" }}
spring-boot-starter-opentelemetry-bom = {group = "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation", name = "opentelemetry-instrumentation-bom", version = { ref = "opentelemetry" }}

...

opentelemetry = "2.7.0"

And the gradle dependency setup with
plugins { 
    alias(libs.plugins.dependency.management)
}
        
plugins.apply(libs.plugins.dependency.management.get().pluginId)
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        ...
        mavenBom(libs.spring.boot.starter.opentelemetry.bom.get().toString())
        mavenBom(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

I'm using the two micrometer packages, namely micrometer-tracing and micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel. As well as the standard actuator and web spring boot startups
I just can't seem to find that class on Google at all to even try to explicitly include the library it seems to be missing. I removed all configuration and left it at default as well thinking maybe there was a conditional I just wasn't seeing within the otel series of config options, but nothing is getting rid of this ClassNotFoundException
I basically just followed the instructions here, with the issues stated earlier.

Getting same error

Ok so for anyone else having this issue, at least for my setup, the BOM was not explicitly setting the right opentelemetry-api-incubator version. It was pulling the latest and greatest when left to it's own devices, which has removed DoubleGauge, while the 1.37.0-alpha version does have DoubleGauge. Everything else seems to set 1.37.0 explicitly when looking at a dependency analyzer which is why I'm wondering if this is perhaps a bug in the BOM setup though I really can't say since I wasn't seeing the issue when searching for it earlier.
But yeah, bottom line, set maven or gradle or whatever you use to explicitly use the 1.37.0-alpha version if you are using version 2.7.0 or below of the opentelemetry starter and that should fix your issue.

Same error here.
Could you share a working gradle (or other) configuration?
I try to force io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api-incubator to 1.37.0-alpha but still got error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.api.incubator.metrics.DoubleGauge
